# Limit page creation

Tags: tiki-wiki

I (as admin) want to create a few pages in the wiki where the users may/can create subpages or similiar hierarchical structures.

Is it possible to automatically create a hierarchical order (e.g. a few spaces like Tutorials / Info / Resources) and restrict the users from creating pages outside those defined areas?

I already tried to revoke edit rights from the users and use Structures and only granting rights to edit the content of the structures. This seems to work pretty well, but when a user creates a new sub pages he has no rights to edit them later, because the new files get the global rights (no edit permission).

Is there a right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Categories.

1. Create a category for each structure (Tutorials, Info, Resources).
2. Remove the global tiki_p_edit permission from the group, and edit the each category's permission to allow tiki_p_edit for that specific category.
3. Categorize each of the wiki pages within the appropriate structure.
4. Use the wiki "force categorization" option to automatically force newly created pages in the structure to be in the appropriate category.

Comment: This doesn't work too bad, but users of that group can't create new subpages on their own (or I just can't figure out how).

Maybe I'm searching for something else instead of a wiki. I took a look at different CMSes which solve that particular problem better (hierarchical organization with automated navigation generation)